# Finding difference between the dates from recent date to same date on next year

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I am doing a birthday remainder app. In that i need to show the no of days left for birthday.
If a user Chooses a particular birthday date in the date picker i need to update automatically how many days left for his birthday from the date he chosen. Can any one help this through coding.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

we can do it using nsdate using we can get the present date and then we have to calculate how many days are there between today date and selected date

Answer (score 1):

Below code is use for the findout the interval between the to date and time for that below code is help for that

```
 NSDateComponents *comp=[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:"Your date is here" options:0] ;

 cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d : %d : %d : %d : %d : %d",comp.year,comp.month,comp.day,comp.hour,comp.minute,comp.second];
```

It may to help for your application

Happy coding

@samuel